# Should I create numerous Activities or make a very long Activity?

Tags: android

Okay here, I was told to make a golf score card app, but I'm stuck as how I implement the scoring per holes.

In golf, each hole has its own scoring and the ones I'm making the app for has as much as 27 holes per game.

I don't know whether I should make the 27 Activities for the 27 Holes
or
Use one Activity and ViewFlip with 27 different identical layouts for the whole thing.

Now I just want to know which is the best idea in tackling this problem

Comment: How are u populating the data ? If I'm guessing correctly ur doing that from a webservice right?

Comment: I'm using an Application Class Singleton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know whether I should make the 27 Activities for the 27 Holes or Use one Activity and ViewFlip with 27 different identical layouts for the whole thing.

The layout for each hole is the same(I assume) so make a single activity with that layout and when it's time to go to the next hole score just update the data in that layout. Even if the layouts for different holes are a little different you still should use a single layout that you update(and of course modify it dynamically).

Don't use a `ViewFlipper` if you plan to flip between 27 identical layouts.

Comment: Wow. That's honestly very simple... I have no idea why I thought about the 27 layouts, but not that.
Jesus christ. thanks man.

But like is there a way to make it look as if I flipped to a different Activity/Layout?